# How to find digits, pad zeros with regex and replace path in Python?

Tags: python, regex, replace, os.path

I am trying to get file paths of all .txt files in a directory and replace the root directory of each file and pad zeros for file path with different padding lengths. Consider an example of the file list:

```
./Old directory/ABC 01/XYZ 1 - M 1.txt
./Old directory/ABC 01/XYZ 1 - M 2.txt
./Old directory/ABC 01/XYZ 1 - M 3.txt
```

Now a require a Python code to give me this output:

```
./New directory/ABC 00001/XYZ 0001 - M 001.txt
./New directory/ABC 00001/XYZ 0001 - M 002.txt
./New directory/ABC 00001/XYZ 0001 - M 003.txt
```

The reproducible code (my effort):

```
import os
import re
files = []
for root, directories, files in os.walk('./Old directory'):
    files = sorted([f for f in files if os.path.splitext(f)[1] in ('.txt')])
    for file in files:
        files.append(os.path.join(root, file))
for file in files:
    file.replace('./Old directory', './New directory')
```

Comment: So what does that code do? How does that differ from what you expected? It doesn't appear to make any effort to pad the digits or implement a regex so far; where's your attempt at that?

Comment: It provides me with the file list of files ending with .txt extension, and replaces the root directory.

Comment: That is where I am stuck. I can get the digits using re.findall(r"[-+]?\d*\.\d+|\d+", file), but don't know about the further steps.

Comment: So why isn't that included in the example, along with inputs and expected and actual outputs? Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. *"What do I do now?"* is not generally a good SO question, though.

Comment: Strings are immutable in Python, which means methods like `str.replace()` and `re.sub()` do **not** alter a string in place; rather, they return a new string that you should assign to a variable. For example: `new_file = file.replace(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that it is that easy, but it looks like you are very close.

```
import re
...
for file in files:
    file = file.replace('./Old directory', './New directory')
    p = re.compile(ur'(\d+)')
    file = re.sub(p, u"000$1", file)
```

[View testing example](https://regex101.com/r/jV0fH3/1)

Answer (score 0):

It is fatal to use the same variable `files` for two different purposes in your code - I changed one instance to `filenames`, and I complemented the code to do the zero-padding.

```
import os
import re
filenames = []
for root, directories, files in os.walk('./Old directory'):
    files = sorted([f for f in files if os.path.splitext(f)[1] in ('.txt')])
    for file in files:
        filenames.append(os.path.join(root, file))
def padzeros(s, m, g, width):   # pad the group g of match m in string s 
    return s[:m.start(g)]+m.group(g).zfill(width)+s[m.end(g):]
for file in filenames:
    file = file.replace('./Old directory', './New directory')
    m = re.search(r'\D+(\d+)\D+(\d+)\D+(\d+)', file)
    # important: pad from last to first match
    file = padzeros(file, m, 3, 3)
    file = padzeros(file, m, 2, 4)
    file = padzeros(file, m, 1, 5)
    print file
```